# Save a pdf from a link in iframe

Tags: php, pdf, iframe

I open a website link with iframe in my website,
The link is a PDF that open with browser or download it with download manager,
So,i want to save PDF of in my server,
Is there a solution for programming?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: I still have not written code, because i didn't find solution.